# DirectShow Graph with a transform filter feeding both preview and capture

Tags: directshow

I have a Transform filter (single input pin, single output pin), which is effectively an Overlay filter for adding text to a video stream.

There is a filter graph running from a capture device, preview to screen renderer (vmr9), and capture to a GMFBridge which sends onwards to a file writer.  There are some intermediate converters and compressors, but to simplify,  lets say this is the part of the Graph that I would like some advice on.

```
[Source Filter] -> [?Smart Tee?] -> capture graph
                                 -> preview graph
```

The Smart Tee may or may not be present based on the available pins on the capture device, but one way or another there is always a preview pin and a capture pin on the source, or the Smart Tee directly after it.

I would like to add a single instance of the transform filter so that its effects are apparent in both the capture and preview.

Obviously the first thing that crosses the mind is :

```
[Source Filter] -> [Transform] -> [Smart Tee] -> capture graph
                                              -> preview graph
```

I have however read that I should not be getting involved at all in what is going on between the source and Smart Tee, I am not clear on if there is some valid technical reason for this, or if it is just because it would not work well with intelligent connect, but could be worked around by manually building the graph.

However,  if I should not be using a Smart Tee for my own aims, would an infinite pin tee work, only connecting to one pin on the capture device?  Maybe :

```
    [Source Filter] -> [Transform] -> [Inf Tee] -> capture graph
   Ignore preview pin                           -> preview graph
```

I would be grateful for any input.

-----------------------Added additional details ---------------------------

The (Most Likely) current Graph would look like this.  Note that the Bridge Sink Filter leads to a further capture segment, which might contain a compressor and write to a file.  There may be more or less colour converters depending on the attached device.  The Overlay filter is RGB24.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve now is to move the Overlay filter before the split between preview Capture, so that its transformation is seen in both the captured file and the preview.

Comment: Where have you read that? The only concerns that you have is that your transform filter should expose the appropriate media types. I don't know the depths of a smart tee, but, if it is conform the standards nothing is wrong with putting a filter in between.

Comment: Thanks Stefan,  That is reassuring, and certainly keeps things simple.  This was where I read that this graph construction was not actually supported / expected.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/335ac5c2-b59a-4bb4-a81e-aca80b5bc849/how-to-connect-custom-filter-before-graphbuilder-automatically-add-smart-tee?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment

Comment: Okay, well, you're not safe yet. As I read it, the smart tee is a special purpose filter. That can make things a bit trickier. Just to clarify: what are you going to transform? Are you modifying a compressed stream?

Comment: Capture hardware can vary,  but almost always is the output of a video blaster type device (analogue to  digital), output is nearly always  YUV, occasionally RGB.  The Transform Filter is RGB24.  So a fuller preview graph might look like `Crossbar -> USB Blaster -> IAT YUV ->Overylay Filter -> Color Space Converter -> VMR9`  So really I would be looking to 'split / Tee' after the Overlay Filter, given the possibility.

Comment: *"What I am trying to achieve now is to move the Overlay filter before the split between preview Capture, so that its transformation is seen in both the captured file and the preview."*, IMO it should just work.

Comment: I'd say you can even move YUV filter before the tee, why would you excessively load system converting twice. Your transform can be placed there as well as long as you need it for both legs, preview and capture.

Comment: Thank you.  So I will take that the consensus is that it is most likely ok to place a transform before the Smart Tee, and I will progress this way.  @RomanR.  Good catch,  yes the YUV filter could certainly also sit before the tee.  Thanks for your attention.